# Track dimensions of an array of refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that returns an array of refs when mapping the `{children}`

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

const children = ["hey", "now", "heeeey", "now"];

const Test = () => {
  const itemRefs = useRef([]);

  const setItemRef = (element, index) => {
    itemRefs.current[index] = element;
  };

  console.log(itemRefs)
  //current: Array(4)
  //0: <div>hey</div>
  //1: <div>now</div>
  //2: <div>heeeey</div>
  //3: <div>now</div>

  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, index) => {
        return (
          <div ref={(element) => setItemRef(element, index)} key={index}>
            {child}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

I have a hook that tracks the dimensions of a supplied ref.

```js
export default function useBoundingRect(ref, limit) {
  const [boundingClient, setBoundingClient] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && ref.current) {
      const set = () => {
        const { x, y, width, height } = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        setBoundingClient({ x, y, width, height });
      };

      set();

      const listener = debounce(limit ? limit : 100, set);

      window.addEventListener("resize", listener);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", listener);
    }
  }, [ref, limit]);

  return boundingClient;
}
```

### How can I track the items in `itemRefs`?

Do I pass the entire object into the hook and modify the hook to return an array of dimensions?

Comment: return an array of dimensions - yes, why not, so what is the problem?

Comment: This is a bit tricky because the length of `children` could change so you need to make sure that you are not changing the number of hooks called.  You probably need to modify the `useBoundingRect` hook itself to handle an array of refs rather than calling it multiple times.  Or somehow call the hook in the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the fundamental rules of refs is that you must call the same amount of refs with each render.  This means that we can't call `useBoundingRect` in a loop because the length of `children` might change.

To get around this, we can create an element `ChildWrapper` that goes around each child.  This element calls the hook and communicates with the parent.

```
const ChildWrapper = ({children, setRect}) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const rect = useBoundingRect(ref);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRect(rect);
  }, [rect]);

  return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>;
};

const Test = () => {
  // an array of rectangle dimensions
  const [rects, setRects] = useState([]);

  // helper to update a rect by index
  const setRect = (index) => (rect) => {
    // I am using slice instead of map to support changes in array length
    setRects((prev) => [
      ...prev.slice(0, index),
      rect,
      ...prev.slice(index + 1)
    ]);
  };

  console.log("rects", rects);

  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, index) => {
        return (
          <ChildWrapper key={index} setRect={setRect(index)}>
            {child}
          </ChildWrapper>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your answer. I never would have thought of anything like that. Though the last hurdle for me then would be to get the dimensions back from `rects` at `  const [rects, setRects] = useState([]);`. Unsure how I could do that.

Comment: Just use the variable `rects` or `rects[i]`.  Is the issue that we don't know the index for a child?  Or do you need to communicate up another level and pass a value to a parent on change?

Comment: The actual end objective here, which I foolishly neglected to mention, is to finish with an array of positions. Literally as simple as [0, -350, -700, -1050, -1400, -1750, -2100, -2450, -2800, -3150] but so that these positions will be responsive and change with resizing of the viewport.

Later... these positions are used to calculate where an animation should snap to

Comment: How do we go from an array of rectangles to that single list?  It just the `y`?  `const array = rects.map( r => r.y )`?

Comment: Sorry very sorry Linda. I altered the hook since I posted the question and it wasn't working with your answer. With the changes I made your answer was returning empty objects. I've reverted it back and now it works as expected. Thank you so very much, what an incredible answer and thank you for your time and patience with my messing up. Think it's time I went to bed!